# fibers of a local diffeomorphism discrete set

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds with or without boundary and $f : M \to N$ be a local diffeomorphism. I have to show that for each point $q$ of $N$, $f^{-1}(q)$ is a discrete subset of $M$. But I am just stuck. The only hint I have is that each point $f^{-1}(q)$ has a neighborhood on which $f$ is injective

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Your hint tells you that for every point $p$ of $f^{-1}(q)$, there is a neighbourhood around it for which only $p$ goes to $q$. If only $p$ goes to $q$, then the rest of the neighbourhood doesn't, and it therefore isn't in $f^{-1}(q)$.

Comment: So each point of the fiber has a neighborhood where $f$ is injective. Can such a neighborhood contain other points of the fiber?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the preimage theorem for maps $f:M \to N$, with dimension $m,n$ respectively and  $m>n$, and $q$ a regular value, then   $f^{-1}(q)$ is a submanifold of dimension $n-k$. Hence, for a local diffeomorphism, $q$ should be a regular value (locally injective) and $M,N$ have the same dimension.

Comment: How does that imply that $f^{-1}(q)$ is a discrete set?

Comment: @Keith It's a zero dimensional manifold. It has to be locally diffeomorphic to a single point.